# populating label with an array of Strings

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of string and I would like to populate my label with them

This is what i have so far but doesn't seem to work

```
Dim _items() As String = {"Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Mango"}

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    label1 = _item

End Sub
```

This is how I want my output to be

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, is that really a Label? It looks like a TextBox.

I'll assume it's a Label. Make sure the Label has some properties set in the designer to allow multi-line text and a large size like that:

```
label1.AutoSize = false
```

Your question boils down to these two questions:

1. How can I put text on a label?
2. How can I change a list of strings into a single [carriage return line feed] delimited string?

This will address both

```
Dim _items() As String = {"Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Mango"}

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' change the array of strings into a single string delimited with crlf
    Dim delimitedString = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, _items)
    ' set the label's text property to your string
    label1.Text = delimitedString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label1.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, items)
```